# Choose and use accent from another font without specifying the fontname every time

Tags: xetex, fontspec, accents

I want to import all accents from another font in XeLaTeX. I can import specific letters from another font using xetex, like the example below. But if the font used in fontspec does not have the unicode character defined, then it outputs garbage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{iftex}

\ifxetex
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\else
\usepackage[LGR,T2A,LY1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{OldStandard}
\usepackage{pdfrender, xcolor}
\fi

\ifpdftex
\pdfrender{StrokeColor=black,TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.1pt}
\makeatletter\let\normalrender\PdfRender@NormalColorHook\let\PdfRender@NormalColorHook\@empty\newcommand*{\textnormalrender}[1]{\begingroup\normalrender#1\endgroup}\makeatother
\else
\newcommand{\fakebold}{2}
\setmainfont[FakeBold=\fakebold,ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,BoldItalicFont=OldStandard-BoldItalic.otf,SmallCapsFont={OldStandard-Regular.otf},SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,FakeBold=\fakebold,RawFeature=+smcp},BoldFont=OldStandard-Bold.otf,BoldFeatures={FakeBold=0,SmallCapsFont=OldStandard-Bold.otf,SmallCapsFeatures={RawFeature=+smcp}},BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=0}]{ModernMTStd-Extended.otf}
\setmathfont[FakeBold=\fakebold,]{NewCMMath-Book.otf}
\setmathfont[range=it,FakeBold=\fakebold]{Old Standard Italic}
\setmathfont[range={\symfrak},FakeBold=\fakebold]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={\int},Scale=2,]{Old Standard Italic}
\setmathfont[range={\sum,\prod},Scale=1.7]{Old Standard Italic}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits)[Scale=MatchUppercase,FakeBold=\fakebold]{Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Latin)[Uppercase=Italic,Lowercase=Italic,FakeBold=\fakebold,Scale=MatchUppercase]{ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=Tex}
\fi

\title{\textsc{Title}}
\author{\textsc{Me}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{\textsc{\textbf{Theorem}}}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    Checking \'{a},\"{a},\H{a},\"{}
    
\end{document}
```

Here is the output[image]

I can probably switch to a different font every time I need to access `\H` but I think it's better if I could just do what I did for other fonts. For example,

```
\setmathfont[range=it,FakeBold=\fakebold]{Old Standard Italic}
```

allowed me to use all letters from the italic version of the Old Standard font. I don't want to manually undeclare/declare all the instances I need.

Comment: Not necessarily related to thequesion, but I'm not sure it can end well if you load both unicode-math and mathspec, they are taking radically different approaches to mathematics unicode-math is for opentype math fonts, mathspec is for setting math using opentype text fonts and classic tex math layout

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Honestly, I don't know any other way to get the output that I want. Getting to this point was hard enough and I am still struggling a little making it perfect. For example, this issue.

Comment: it looks like you are using mathsec really, Id just not load unicode-math in that case, since you are over-riding all of its settings

Comment: I had to use unicode-math for choosing the math font, changing the math letters to Old Standard Italic and customizing the sum/product/int symbols. I wasn't sure if the same can be accomplished using mathspec.

Comment: well just use unicode-math then, honestly anything that comes out if you load both is just accidental. but your question is actually about text accents not math see `texdoc fontspec`  page 53 on how to adjust the accent commands

Comment: thank you. I was reading the fontspec documentation, didn't go that far yet.  Will look into it. As for mathspec, I will try to remove it if possible. Currently I am using it to change the latin alphabets because I really like the alphabet of the font I am using.